# Is connecting via 2 VPNs secure

Tags: vpn, security

I know there are VPN services like Speedify that you can connect to with 2 internet connections wired and wifi to combine them on their servers to get a faster connection and then connect to what you're trying to connect to with one IP.

I already have a VPN I need to use though so are there any security implications of connecting via 2 different VPNs?
Dose the first only see your encrypted traffic/packets that it sends to the second?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

When using a VPN you are creating a connection into a network to which you would not otherwise have any access. (corp network, etc.) If you are connected to more than one, you become a potential insecure bridge between them. While a node in one network cannot directly reach anything in the other network(s), *you* can, so any compromised thing in one network can get to you and then into other networks.

(It's only as secure as the machines connecting to the VPNs.)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your definition of *secure*.

VPN can provide a secure link over an insecure network (e.g. the Internet) where the transported data cannot be listened in or manipulated by any third party. It's often called an *overlay network* because it creates a network (link) on top of another network.

The nodes you connect through VPN become direct link partners. That link can be used for remote access into a private network (*client VPN*), to connect remote networks (*site-to-site VPN*), or to provide Internet access through a service that obscures your own public IP address ("*VPN service*").

Since a direct network link is a potential attack vector, both link partners need to either trust each other wholeheartedly or each provide a reliable firewall service on the link. Of course, connecting multiple VPN partners extends the need for trust or a decent firewall.

Routing your (Internet) traffic through a VPN link enables your link partner to examine that traffic. Of course, encrypted data (SSL/TLS) cannot be inspected unless SSL deep inspection is used.